# Why is using DBI's variable-binding causing a MySQL query to fail?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

For some reason, using DBI's bind parameter feature for the below AES key is causing a query to fail to find any rows.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:database=thedb;host=localhost');

my $aes_key = 'X`ku@wC_BI\SgY[S%/<iaB>&VXd5zDA+';
print length($aes_key), "\n";

my $test = $dbh->selectrow_hashref("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE id = ?\
 AND AES_DECRYPT(enc_pass, '$aes_key') IS NOT NULL", undef, 1);
print $test->{'COUNT(*)'}, "\n";

$test = $dbh->selectrow_hashref("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE id = ?\
 AND AES_DECRYPT(enc_pass, ?) IS NOT NULL", undef, 1, $aes_key);
print $test->{'COUNT(*)'}, "\n";
```

Output:

```
32
1
0
```

I see there's an escaped "S" in `$aes_key`, but it doesn't *appear* to have any impact on the variable since `\S` isn't a valid escape sequence in Perl. I do suspect that or something similar is the problem, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you bind a variable to a placeholder, MySQL uses exactly what is in the Perl variable.  When you interpolate a variable into a SQL statement, MySQL treats it as a string literal.

MySQL handles unknown backslash escapes by removing the backslash.  As MySQL string literals, `'\S'` and `'S'` are equivalent.  When you use placeholders, `'\S'` in a Perl variable is equivalent to `'\\S'` as a MySQL string literal.

It appears that you wound up storing the key incorrectly in the database by using a string literal, so now it can't be found when you use a placeholder.  I'll bet that if you change the line where you initialize `$aes_key` to

```
my $aes_key = 'X`ku@wC_BISgY[S%/<iaB>&VXd5zDA+'; # note missing backslash
```

then the results would change to

```
31
1
1
```

because that's the key that MySQL has actually been using.

Answer (score 3):

> I see there's an escaped "S" in $aes_key, but it doesn't appear to have any impact on the variable since \S isn't a valid escape sequence in Perl. I do suspect that or something similar is the problem, though.

It is and it isn't. With DBI placeholders, there's no interpretation of escape sequences at all.

The problem is that mysql *has* been interpreting your escape sequences when you pasted the key into SQL:

```
mysql> select 'X`ku@wC_BI\SgY[S%/<iaB>&VXd5zDA+', length('X`ku@wC_BI\SgY[S%/<iaB>&VXd5zDA+') as len;
+---------------------------------+-----+
| X`ku@wC_BISgY[S%/<iaB>&VXd5zDA+ | len |
+---------------------------------+-----+
| X`ku@wC_BISgY[S%/<iaB>&VXd5zDA+ |  31 |
+---------------------------------+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

See? No backslash (if you put a backslash before a character that has no special meaning, you just get the same character, but without the backslash). So when you pass the key into mysql *correctly* it doesn't work, because you were using it incorrectly before.